# How to resolve SSPI context error without changing Service Account from MSSQL

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-8.1

There is a issue while connecting from new Windows 8.1 Clients to SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. The SQL Service running under account Domain\mssqlservice on a machine thats works fine I get this output from `setspn -l domain\mssqlservice`

```
C:\>setspn -l domain\mssqlservice 
Registrierte Dienstprinzipalnamen
(SPN) für CN=MSSQLService,CN=Users,DC=domain, DC=local,DC=tld:
        MSSQLSvc/mssql.domain.local.tld:1433
        MSSQLSvc/mssql.domain.local.tld
        MSSQLSERVER/mssql.domain.local.tld:1433
```

On a windows 8.1 machine that don't work I get this output:

```
C:\>setspn -l domain\msssqlservice 
FindDomainForAccount: Fehler beim
Aufrufen von DsGetDcNameWithAccountW mit dem R ückgabewert 0x0000054B.
Konto kockiren wurde nicht gefunden.
```

On [this Post](http://joshrobi.blogspot.de/2010/01/how-to-fix-sql-server-error-cannot.html) I found a solution but, I can't change the Service Account who runs the SQL Service. Some application need this service delegation. But how I can realize that it works on my Windows 8.1 Clients?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fix works for everyone, but deleting all the SPNs with MSSQLSvc fixed it for me.

```
setspn -d [spn name] [server name]
```

With this you don't have to run it as local system.  You can run it with a domain account.